# In the nature-nurture war, what wins? Nature or nurture?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, psychology

We focus on not only nature, the genetic factors of behavior, but also nurture, the environmental factors of behavior. But how can environmental factors be separate from genetic factors? Don't genetic influences slip in? Unless the environment is randomly "out there" independent of genes, isn't every single thing people do influenced by their genes? How does nurture or social constructivism alone get to the bottom of *why* people do what they do?

Comment: There's a case that nurture is determined by nature. Some theistic theories likely disagree.

Comment: "How does nurture or social constructivism alone get to the bottom of why people do what they do?" -  It doesn't. At this point is there any serious thinker who denies that genes play a part in shaping human behavior, even if the expression of those genes is also heavily conditioned by environment and experience? Unless you can be more specific the question seems to be fighting a straw man.

Comment: @BrianZ Social studies have a tendency to greatly understate the effect of genes and biology (nature). Practitioners know to deny this as doing so signals moderation and comprehensiveness, but social constructivism remains a dominating implicit assumption across the field in the work published. There is a battle being fought within these fields between those who believe both nature and nurture are significant (evolutionary psychology, for example) and those who believe nurture is all that needs to be taken into account (the SSSM - Standard Social Science Model, for example).

Comment: When you get to the "bottom" every single thing gets influenced by every other single thing. This is why we focus on dominant influences only, "slipping in" does not cut it.  Social constructivists simply think that whatever genes contribute gets scrubbed and painted over so many times that it is by an large washed out.

Comment: @Conifold Perhaps, but it is scientifically illiterate. Denying behavioral genetics, as an example of one of many fields denied, is science denialism. It is an extreme anti-science position motivated by vogue ideas inherited from the humanities. Whether humans are born with two legs or six, which is determined by genetics, has a foundational effect on culture. Whether or not humans have spinal columns or mammalian brains, which is determined by genetics, has an impossible-to-overstate effect on culture.

Answer (score 2):

Vervoeke, a cognitive scientist, has pointed out that in our secular world the place of wisdom is replaced by the "market" as a unifying ideology with its talk of competition and the like. And is this not exemplified by your headline question?

> In the nature-nurture war, what wins? Nature or nurture?

Most people who have seriously reflected on this have not considered it as a 'war' that requires a 'win' by one side or the other. This is the very simple minded dualism of the market ideology of the West. Daoism had a much more sophisticated view where it is observed both are actively involved and syntheses occur through, to use Hegel's term, sublation.

Comment: Nice point on the market terminology used everywhere, and the dialectical interaction

Answer (score 1):

It is an interplay of factors.

It is a provable fact that same genes can be expressed differenty on different environments, and this can even be a huge difference, ie some genes may even be blocked from expressing. (1)

> Genes exert their influence by encoding proteins. The level of such
> gene activity, however, is a regulated process. As molecules, genes
> are subject to regulation by intracellular factors that, in turn, are
> a reflection of environmental factors. Neither genes nor environment
> dominates development; rather there is continual interaction between
> genes and the environment. Phenotype emerges as a function of this
> constant dialogue, and any effort to ascribe percentage values to
> isolated variables is likely to be biologically meaningless.

It should be noted that social behavior is a complex process and no one really attributes it exclusively and finally to genes, which only provide general tendencies for general things. That is, **a gene does not prescribe one possible outcome, but instead, a set of possible outcomes** (all compatible with the same gene, which can be quite different and not all of which are known beforehand).

Furthermore, it is not known how genes interact together, it is highly unlikely it is simply a linear  relatiionship.

Given that the environment changes by many factors, even agents' own actions, the interplay is quite stochastic.

So roughly there is an interplay of factors. One can say a dialectical interplay.

PS: Unless one is a theoretical determinist, it is very likely the world has some indeterminacies involved, and practically this is the case, regardless of theoretical commitment.

Some references:

1. [Environmentally induced gene expression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK43787/)
2. [How pollution and other environmental effects can affect human DNA](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2021/06/this-is-how-our-gene-expression-can-be-altered-by-the-environment/)